# How to map the values in first dataframe based on second dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, mapping

I have two dataframes. The df1 is the main df and df2 is reference dataframe.
The  df1 look like this:

```
u1d               Status: Partisipant status         Country:Country from URL
122                           2                                4    
123                           4                                11
124                           1                                14
```

and df2 look like this which is a reference.

[image]

I want that in df1 my all values map to code for example in  **Status: Participant status**  2 is Terminated so it should map in place of 2 as Terminated and all the other columns. I have about 2000 columns so i need also efficient way.

Comment: @jezrael can you help?

Comment: ya, I create answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution is reshape by [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), add new columns by [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and last [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df = (df1.melt('u1d', var_name='Variable_name', value_name='Value Code')
         .merge(df2, how='left')
         .pivot('u1d','Variable_name','Value Name'))
```

Another idea:

```
for c in df1.columns[1:]:
    s = df2[df2['Variable_name'].eq(c)].set_index('Value Code')['Value Name']
    df1[c] = df1[c].map(s)
```

Comment: Do you think it will map all the columns based on df2? I was expecting to create nested dictionary based on df2 and then map it.

Comment: @s_khan92 - Added another solution

Comment: Getting error for uuid and when i change `df1.columns[1:]` 1 ->3 then other columns error

Comment: I actually created dict based on df2 `d = {}
for i in df['Varaible_Name'].unique():
    d[i] = [{df['Value Code'][j]: df['Value Name'][j]} for j in df[df['Varaible_Name']==i].index]` and then i guess it would be best to map but i am not sure how to use nested dictionary to map multiple columns

Comment: and for first solution i got this error: `ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and float64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat`

Comment: @s_khan92 - So error means there are some non numeric columns, my solution working if all columns without `uid` are numeric.

Comment: ah.. I have about 2000 columns

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209359/discussion-between-s-khan92-and-jezrael).